# Mock Requests Function in PySpark UDF

Tags: unit-testing, pyspark, mocking, pytest, databricks

I have the following UDF in PySpark under `src/my_funcs/`

```
@F.udf(returnType=T.ArrayType(T.ArrayType(T.StringType())))
def get_details(details_url: str) -> list[list[str]]:
   details = requests.get(details_url)
   details = details.json()
   details = # Some logic
   return details
```

Now I want to unit test this UDF. For that, I did the following:

```
from unittest import mock

@mock.patch("src.my_funcs.requests.get")
def test_get_details(mock_requests_get, spark):
   request_json_response = # Expected result of .json()
   mock_requests_get.return_value = mock.Mock(**{"status_code":200, "json.return_value":request_json_response})
   input_data = [(1, "random_invalid_url")]
   input_schema = ["ID", "details_url"]
   input_df = spark.createDataFrame(input_data, input_schema)

   expected_data = # expected array
   expected_schema = ["ID", "details_url", "details"]
   expected_df = spark.createDataFrame(expected_data, expected_schema)
   
   transformed_df = input_df.withColumn("details", get_details("details_url")
   assert sorted(expected_df.collect()) == sorted(transformed_df.collect())
```

I keep getting the error

```
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'random_invalid_url': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant https://random_invalid_url?
```

This error makes it appear that my mocking is not working.

If I remove the UDF decorator from the get_details function, and test the function without Spark, the mocking works and the unit test succeeds. So I assume the error is related to how Spark works. How can I fix this and test the UDF on a Spark DataFrame? Is the error because of how Spark executes the UDF? Do I need to mock it in a different way, or is it just not possible?

Not sure if relevant, but the spark session is created as a pytest fixture like this

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("UnitTest").getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to unit test your logic inside `get_details`, I would suggest you extract that code into a separate function and test it (no Spark or mock necessary).

If you do not want to refactor your code, you can leave `get_details` as is, but instead of using `@F.udf` decorator call it as function before passing it to Spark methods (you will need to mock requests but will still avoid Spark):

```
udf_get_details = F.udf(get_details, returnType=T.ArrayType(T.ArrayType(T.StringType())))
transformed_df = input_df.withColumn("details", udf_get_details("details_url"))
```

Even if you did manage to run it through Spark, you would only:

1. be checking if Spark is correctly calling UDFs
2. make the tests run slower

Comment: It is not the answer I hoped for, since I prefer using the decorator for cleanliness. I updated my code to create a function, and then call the F.UDF function to create a udf. Unit testing the original function works now. Thanks for this!
PS: I don't agree with your first remark on testing the Pyspark function. Making the Spark UDF unit test work will test correctly calling the UDF AND the logic of the UDF.

Answer (score -1):

I think your mock should just be requests.get, assuming you're using the get function of the requests package. Now it is mocking a requests.get function in your src.my_funcs file, which probably doesn't exist.

Comment: This is not true. You need to specify where the function is called.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch

Comment: I recommend you read your link more thoroughly. As requests is imported, (the function used requests.get) my way of patching is correct.

Comment: Here is even an example that mocks the requests library (Although not in a spark context). Adding src.my_func is needed.  https://youtu.be/M46H4GIdfl0?feature=shared&t=848
I was also make it work by following bzu's suggestion, again by patching src.my_func_requests.get